# How to scale an image to match scaled skeleton with Kinect

Tags: image, scale, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I have an skeleton scaled to a fixed height in screen( 2/3ths of the screen) , now I want to scale the image(with background substraction) to match that skeleton. I am using this method below to find out the target distance to get a fixed height in screen( no matter how far or near the user is), then I compute a vertical translation to get the skeleton with the foot joints on the bottom of the image.

```
void KinectClass::ScaleJoints(){

//Target Height in screen

double targetAdultHeightScreen = windowHeight*5/6;

double originalAdultDistance = players[0].hipCenter.z;

// Original Height in Screen
originalHeightScreenAdult = SkeletonToScreen(players[0].rightFoot, windowWidth, windowHeight).y - SkeletonToScreen(players[0].head, windowWidth, windowHeight).y;

// Target distance to get target height
AdultscaleDistance = originalHeightScreenAdult * originalAdultDistance/ targetAdultHeightScreen;

//New headJoint scaled to compute vertical translation
Vector4 headJointAdult = {players[0].head.x  ,players[0].head.y , AdultscaleDistance,players[0].head.w};

//Vertical translation
transAdult = windowHeight/6 - SkeletonToScreen(headJointAdult, windowWidth, windowHeight).y;

scaleRatioAdult = originalHeightScreenAdult/targetAdultHeightScreen;

}
```

Something like this:

[image: Scaled Skeleton]

Now I have to scale the bitmap image (that now is the size of the screen) so my skeleton match with the image.

```
D2D1_SIZE_F screenSize = renderTarget_->GetSize();
//D2D1_RECT_F rec = D2D1::RectF(0,  0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

The problem is that now I have to scale the image to match the skeleton which has not only the user but the entire scene(color stream of the kinect).

**Which transformations do I have to apply to that bitmap?**

Answer (score 0):

The key to such transformation is to use the following mapping function, per skeleton joint:

`public ColorImagePoint MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(SkeletonPoint skeletonPoint, ColorImageFormat colorImageFormat);`

Once you translated all joints into the color plane, you can perform any scaling you want on the color bitmap, and just perform the exact same scaling on the translated skeleton-color points.